gpg: Can't check signature: No public key | Debian Raspberry Pi Images
I am having some issue verifying the Raspberry Pi image for the RPI 2B of Debian.
Steps followed:
Download Files:
wget https://raspi.debian.net/tested/20231109_raspi_2_bookworm.img.xz && wget https://raspi.debian.net/tested/20231109_raspi_2_bookworm.img.xz.sha256 && wget https://raspi.debian.net/tested/20231109_raspi_1_bookworm.img.xz.sha256.asc

user@computer:~/ISOs/DebianRPI2B$ gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-keys 64E6EA7D 6294BE9B 09EA8AC3
gpg: key 42468F4009EA8AC3: "Debian Testing CDs Automatic Signing Key <debian-cd@lists.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key DA87E80D6294BE9B: "Debian CD signing key <debian-cd@lists.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: key 988021A964E6EA7D: "Debian CD signing key <debian-cd@lists.debian.org>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 3
gpg:              unchanged: 3
user@computer:~/ISOs/DebianRPI2B$ gpg --with-fingerprint --verify 20231109_raspi_1_bookworm.img.xz.sha256.asc
gpg: Signature made Fri 10 Nov 2023 12:09:57 PM MST
gpg:                using EDDSA key 4D14050653A402D73687049D2404C9546E145360
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
user@computer:~/ISOs/DebianRPI2B$ 

Has Debian changed their GPG keys? Or am I making a mistake verifying them?
Cryptography isn't my specialist and I sincerely apologize if any mistakes are being made on my end.
Thank you so much for all of your time and energy. I immensely appreciate any support you can provide.

These images aren’t provided by the Debian project, but by a Debian Developer; this is indicated in the footer:

This site is not an official Debian project. While the maintainer (Gunnar Wolf) is a Debian Developer, content herein provided should be considered unofficial.

The signatures are made with Gunnar’s key, not a Debian image signing key. You need to retrieve the appropriate key:
gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-keys 4D14050653A402D73687049D2404C9546E145360

